# combining repmat and transpose in julia

Tags: vectorization, julia

I'm porting some code from R to julia to get familiar with the language, and I found a few patterns that don't translate smoothly. Consider the following function,

```
# Ricatti-Bessel and derivatives up to nmax, vectorised over x
function rb(x, nmax)

  n = 1:nmax
  nu = 0.5 + [0, n]

  bj = hcat([besselj(nu, _x) for _x in x]...).'
  # ^ first question ^ 
  sq = repmat(sqrt(pi/2*x), 1, nmax+1)

  bj .*= sq
  xm = repmat(x, 1, nmax)
  nm = repmat(n', length(x), 1)
  # ^ second question ^ 

  dpsi = bj[:,n] - nm .* bj[:,n+1] ./ xm 
  psi = bj[:,n+1]
  return psi, dpsi # it'd be nice to return a "named list" instead

end
# rb(1:5,3)
```

- first question: is this the best way to get a matrix with nmax columns and length(x) rows using `besselj()`? I had to scratch my head for quite a while before finding a pattern that works.
- second question: I find myself constantly having to transpose objects, in and/or out of repmat, is there an alternative where I can specify the output size and fill direction (row-wise or col-wise)?

Maybe I'm taking a wrong approach with the whole thing: I'm used to work with vectorised functions (in R, and old memories of Matlab), because they're typically the shortest route to fast routines for linear algebra.
Would it make more sense to keep x a scalar throughout, and loop only at the highest-level? I fear that by doing so, I'll be unable to make use of fast matrix/vector functions from BLAS etc. and essentially rewriting them in julia, not to mention the obvious loss of readability.
I should stress that I'm interested in optimum performance, as this function will be called internally a large number of times, for many values of x.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your first question, I'd replace it with following matrix comprehension:

```
nu = (0:nmax)+0.5
bj = [besselj(i,j) for j in x, i in nu]
```

For your second, I think a good principle for writing high performance code in Julia is avoiding unnecessary allocations (and reading the [performance tips](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/performance-tips/), of course!) Julia generates very fast instructions when it can - this is why `for` loops are perfectly fine, and it isn't really critical to vectorize anything other than linear algebra (e.g. matrix multiplication). What it doesn't do a good job is avoiding allocating memory that isn't necessary (temporary matrices like your `sq`). I replaced the `bj`/`sq` lines with just the following

```
nu = (0:nmax)+0.5
bj = [besselj(i,j)*sqrt(pi/2*j) for j in x, i in nu]
```

Which is nice because its just one allocation, and before we had (assuming we start from my answer to Q1):

1. Allocate `bj`
2. Allocate `sq`
3. Allocate `bj.*sq` and re-bind `bj` to this new memory

(Note that `.*=` is **not** an in-place operation!)

Your request for a "named list" is probably best met right now either by making a `type` for the return of this function (this isn't an expensive operation at all, and is very common in e.g. Julia's matrix factorization code, where multiple values need to be returned). Alternatively, you could return a `Dict`, but that doesn't feel idiomatic.

For the `dpsi` line, I'll give you two options. The first is another matrix comprehension:

```
dpsi = [ bj[i,j] - j * bj[i,j+1] / i 
           for i in 1:length(x), j in 1:nmax]
```

and the other is for loop-y:

```
dpsi = zeros(length(x),nmax)
for i in 1:length(x), j in 1:nmax
  dpsi[i,j] = bj[i,j] - j * bj[i,j+1] / i
end
```

In both cases, I'm avoiding allocations of temporaries. Again, your orginal has the following allocations:

1. For `xm`
2. For `nm`
3. For `bj[:,n]` (this will change to be a view in 0.4)
4. For `bj[:,n+1]` (ditto)
5. For `nm .* bj[:,n+1]`
6. For `nm .* bj[:,n+1] ./ xm`
7. For the whole result

and both the versions I propose have only one allocation, and are probably closer to the original mathematical statement of the problem

My final version is

```
function myrb(x, nmax)
  bj   = [ besselj(i,j)*sqrt(pi/2*j)
              for j in x, i in (0:nmax)+0.5]
  dpsi = [ bj[i,j] - j * bj[i,j+1] / i 
              for i in 1:length(x), j in 1:nmax]
  psi  = bj[:,2:nmax+1]
  return psi, dpsi
end
```

I don't know much at all about `besselj`, but I'm guessing it is by the slowest part of this whole thing, so all this probably doesn't matter much in terms of speed in this particular case. Benchmarking this micro case suggests as much:

```
# original
elapsed time: 9.7578e-5 seconds (7176 bytes allocated)
elapsed time: 7.2644e-5 seconds (7176 bytes allocated)
elapsed time: 7.5709e-5 seconds (7176 bytes allocated)
# revised
elapsed time: 2.7536e-5 seconds (728 bytes allocated)
elapsed time: 2.7097e-5 seconds (728 bytes allocated)
elapsed time: 1.6601e-5 seconds (728 bytes allocated)
```

You can confirm this with the profiler (although I had to use much larger inputs:)

```
@profile myrb(1:500,300)
Profile.print()
```

On my machine there were 429 samples collected in the function, 426 of which were in the `bessel.jl` file inside Julia, 2 were for `dpsi`, and 1 was for `psi`.

Comment: many thanks for the tips, I'll go through this in more details. A quick follow-up though: `besselj()`  being vectorised with respect to its first argument, isn't it a bit wasteful to iterate over nu?

Comment: There is no waste, unless the besselj shares something between the arguments. Most vectorized functions in Julia are just a for loop version of the scalar function - in fact, its been proposed to remove them to make this more obvious as its a bit of a hangover pattern from MATLAB

Comment: In fact, you can see the source at https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/special/bessel.jl, and indeed its simply using the `@vectorize_1arg` to generate a vectorized version.

Comment: thanks, I guess I expected a true vectorisation in this case because the [Amos routine generates a sequence of values from 1 to n](https://github.com/JuliaLang/openspecfun/blob/master/amos/zbesj.f#L14), ideally one would want to leverage that directly

Comment: If you could file an issue on the Julia github page about that, that'd be great - its possible that its just been overlooked.

Comment: I'll do that. Just for the sake of completeness, could you suggest a good way to use `besselj([0, 1:nmax], x)` here, assuming it did return a column vector more efficiently than with the `for i in nu` double comprehension?

Comment: I think your solution would be good, although you can include `*sqrt(pi/2*j)` in it of course. i.e. `bj = hcat([ besselj((0:nmax)+0.5,j)*sqrt(pi/2*j) for j in x]...)'`

Comment: thanks for all the tips, it's very helpful. Last question, you mention `Note that .*= is not an in-place operation!`, which is another surprise for me. Where can I read more about this?

Comment: In the documentation at http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/mathematical-operations/#updating-operators, but search the mailing lists and the issues page for some more discussion on the merits

Comment: it's not really covered in the docs though, is it? The "Updating operators" doesn't list `.*=` and its cousins, they're only listed in "Operator Precedence". The fact that `a op= b` always gets replaced by `a = a op b` is not entirely clear either from the docs alone. I read the [github discussions](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/249) this morning, but couldn't quite figure out what was decided in the end. I think it could be made clearer in the docs, I may submit a patch when I get more used to the language.

Comment: That'd be excellent if you could, and a great way to get started. It really caught me out when starting, because I tried to overload it and then I realized it wasn't a true operator (i.e. gets lowered to x=x+y in parsing phase).